# Obtaining the value of an element and the innerhtml of its child element with an onClick?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm trying to make a simple tictactoe game and starting off, I've run into a problem. I'm planning to have a unique value associated with each table cell (td) and a unique id with each Div inside them.

So my plan is to have an onClick event with each td element that takes both of these values as parameters. However when I tried to do a simpler version where I simply console.log'd the value of the td element all I got was undefined. So I'm wondering whats wrong with this code.

```js
function valueToggle(child, parent){
  console.log(parent. value)
//this function takes the child node and the parents node's value, it then logs the value of the paret node.
}

function playerGo(num){
  if(num % 2){
    this.innerHtml = "X"
}
  else{
    this.innerHtml = "O"
}
//this function wi;; signal who's go it is, allowing the value Toggle to
//set the right value to what is clicked next
}

function reset(){
//this resets the game
}
function didYouWin(){
//CHecks to see if a player has won every time a move is made
}
```

```css
#game{
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
border: 2.5px solid black;
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 80px;
}
#cell-1{

}
#cell-2{

}
#cell-3{

}
#cell-4{

}
#cell-5{
  background-color:
}
#cell-6{
  background-color:
}
#cell-7{
  background-color:
}
#cell-8{
  background-color:
}
#cell-9{
  background-color:
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Anton Game</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./antonvers.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="game">
        <div id="player">
            <h2>
                <span id="pShow">Player:</span>
                <span id="pColor">X</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <table id="board" cellpadding="0" cellspacing = "0">
            <tr>
                <td onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNode, this)" value = 0>
                    <div id="cell-1">X</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div id="cell-2">O</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div id="cell-3">X</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-4">O</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-5">X</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-6">O</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-7">O</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-8">X</div>
                </td>
                <td  onClick = "valueToggle(this.childNodes, this)" value = 0>
                    <div class="cell-9">O</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="resetButton">
            <button>Reset</button>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="./antonvers.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems here.

First, when you use HTML "onclick" attributes, when a handler is called `this` is set to the element to which the handler is attached, but the handler is not actually bound to the element it's attached to (it's still bound to the window).  If you attach the handler once the HTML has been fully parsed and the DOM has been created `this` will be bound to the element and you would not have to override the `Event` usually passed as the first argument of an event handler.

Second, only `input` elements have value properties, so setting a value attribute on a `td` will not translate into a value property.  You could use a `data-` attribute to simulate this, or obtain the value by examining the custom "value" attribute with `.getAttribute()`

I've modified your snippet to show possible corrections:

```js
var player = 1;

function valueToggle(event){
//this function takes the child node and the parents node's value, it then logs the value of the paret node.
  let div = event.target.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = ["X","O"][player%2];
}

function playerGo(num){
  if(num % 2) {
    this.innerHTML = "X"
  }
  else {
    this.innerHTML = "O"
  }
//this function wi;; signal who's go it is, allowing the value Toggle to
//set the right value to what is clicked next
}

function reset(){
//this resets the game
}
function didYouWin(){
//CHecks to see if a player has won every time a move is made
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    for (let td of document.querySelectorAll("#board td")) {
        td.onclick = valueToggle;
    }
});
```

```css
#game{
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

td {
border: 2.5px solid black;
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Anton Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./antonvers.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="player">
            <h2>
                <span id="pShow">Player:</span>
                <span id="pColor">X</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <table id="board" cellpadding="0" cellspacing = "0">
            <tr>
                <td data-value="0"><div id="cell-1"></div></td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div id="cell-2"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div id="cell-3"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-4"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-5"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-6"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-7"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-8"></div>
                </td>
                <td data-value="0">
                    <div class="cell-9"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="resetButton">
            <button>Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./antonvers.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, one small thing. I was trying to set the new value inside the element to "O" after it gets console lod'd but .innerHTML and .innerText didnt seem to work. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Problem is you're probably setting it on the wrong node.  The first child of your `td` elements is actually an empty text node, and you want to set it on the div, which is the 2nd child.  I've modified the answer to show one (perhaps not optimal) way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log(parent.getAttribute('value'))` instead of `parent.value`.

From the MDN [documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

> getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string);

Comment: The window has neither a value property nor a value attribute, The result will still be `undefined`

Comment: @Tibrogargan I would wholeheartedly say that your answer is more thorough and therefore presumably more helpful; however, fwiw, I copied & edited the snippet and ran the code, which indeed logged the value.